# What kind of bloody hack is ",this.uiDialogTitlebar).html(f||"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have rebuilt my website with ASP.NET MVC and using all the goodies from that like jQuery.
Recently, I'm constantly getting couple of times per day error notification from my website about: Illegal characters in path
The request URL includes my domain, my JS folder and then a piece of weird JS syntax in it.
Here is an example:

Exception information:
    Exception type: System.ArgumentException
    Exception message: Illegal characters in path.

Request information:
    Request URL: http://[MyDomain]/Scripts/,this.uiDialogTitlebar).html(f||
    Request path: /Scripts/,this.uiDialogTitlebar).html(f||

So, my questions is:
What kind of bloody hack is this guy trying to use?

So far, my website reports all these as error, but I'm just curious.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, it is either just a poorly written spider or you are generating some odd HTML that a reasonably written spider can't process properly.

Answer (score 0):

You got any:

`<a href="javascript:someFunctionCallHereMaybeLike__doPostBackLol()">link text</a>`

links in your site? The .NET framework is notorious in generating f*cked up code like this. If your site do then it´s probably as David Dorward says, it´s a bot that tries to follow that link and thus generating an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an XSS test. There are malicious bots that spider the internet looking for vulnerable servers.   If this is the case it is likely that you would see other strange traffic across your site.

Common attack strings look like the this:

xss:

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

sql injection:

```
1 ' or 1=1 -- 

' or benchmark(1000,md5(1)) --
```

directory traversal:

```
../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00
```